# instagram application: test likes and comments

Tags: instagram-api

I have an instagram app that is to be consumed by a java web app. From what I know, likes and comments are locked and I need  to submit a request to get access to them.

My question is: Is there a way to test likes and comments before submitting the approval request(like Facebook)??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running your app in Sandbox mode, you can access data for users that accepted your invitation to Sandbox. So you can invite some of your friends or user your own account to get those likes/comments.